# Shabbos morning (Drasha) sermon before Kaddish of Musaf

Tags: halacha, kaddish, musaf, speeches-addresses, hefsek-interruption

Recently I saw in Halacha that it is inappropriate to have the sermon right before Kaddish of Musaf as it is considered a Hefsek. Yet many Shuls do just that and have the sermon right before Kaddish of Musaf. Is there any justification to do that? What is the source?

Comment: I have sometimes heard a ש״ץ say "השיבנו...‏" after the rabbi's sermon.

Comment: @msh210 I've seen some yeshivish people make a point of doing this -- and a lot of shul traditionalists making a point of *not* doing so -- "give me that old-time religion, it's good enough for me ..."

Comment: While it may (CYLOR) be halachically appropriate to say "השיבנו...‏" after the sermon, it always strikes me as somewhat disrespectful-seeming (doubtless only seeming and not intended), almost as if the ש״ץ were saying "okay, now that that's done, we can get back to what we were doing before we were interrupted". Perhaps it's just me.

Comment: [Chikrei Minhagim](http://www.judaica-world.com/product.asp?dept=0&Product=BMOS1Z) (I think volume 2) discusses this issue and brings down all the various sources. Unfortunately, I don't have the sefer with me and can't find it online, so I can't quote it. Maybe someone else who has the sefer can look it up fill in the specific information.

Comment: "I saw in Halacha..." ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the Taz (S.A. O.C 55:3) only requires a minyan at the time of kadish, the Magen Avraham (69:4, 234:1) and others say that there needs to be a minyan at the time of pesukim/learning for the kadish to go on.

I assume that the shuls don't want to leave the Torahs out and don't want to change the order of davening (and say ashrei after the Torahs are put away), and so rely on the pesukim in the drasha.  Perhaps even the Taz (234:1) would not consider it a hefsek because the drasha is part of the pesukim.

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi Shmuel Kamenetsky in his Sefer brings as the source for a Shabbos morning Drasha prior to Musaf [Brachos 28b first Rashi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14308&st=&pgnum=61).

Answer (score 3):

Literally stumbled upon this source last week:

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4199&st=&pgnum=454 and the following page 455 where the author [Rav Gedalia Felder, zt"l; Posek from Toronto, Ontario, Niftar in 1992] posits that the Drasha is not a Hefsek prior to Kaddish right before Musaf.

Comment: Can you summarize his reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

When one puts on Rabbeinu Tams before musaf on Rosh Chodesh, the custom is for the Chazan to say a pasuk quietly before Musaf because the donning of Tfillin is a Hefsek (though those not wearing Rabbeinu Tam Tfilin don't because just taking of tfillin is not). Perhaps that is what one should do (see LOR!).

Though many say it is also disrespectful to speak before Torah reading (It's like saying "My speech is more important than the Torah").

Speeking after Davening isn't possible because people would run away before.