# May one talk between kaddish and mussaf

Tags: kaddish, musaf, hefsek-interruption

May one talk between kaddish and mussaf?

Our minhag is to take off the t'fillin then on rosh chodesh. Others, like Belz chasidim, put on their rabainu tam t'fillin, say some davenning like shma, and then take them off and daven mussaf. If the answer to my question is "no", then this ought to be considered a hefsek.

I think if a minyan would daven musaph after having had krias hatorah and ashrai elsewhere and would repeat the ashrai to be able to make the kaddish before the musaph, that would  perhaps prove that the kaddish also belongs to musaph, and just as a hefsek is not allowed after ashrai it should not be allowed before the musaph.

Comment: What is the problem with having a hefsek before *musaf*?

Comment: The problem as I see it is that there is a hefsek between the kaddish and the mussaf.

Comment: @preferred What is the problem with a *hefsek* between the *kaddish* and the *mussaf*?

Comment: Not everyone does the tefillin-switching after kaddish. Some take off the tefillin and then say kaddish.

Comment: This is a question of local custom and varies from shul to shul.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, that is what we do.  Easy solution, no hefsek. I wonder if Belzers and others do the switch before or after Kaddish?

Comment: @Tatpurusha Is it? How do you know?

Comment: I can name 2 minyanim I have spent time in. One said Kaddish, then had people take off tefillin, the other has them take tefillin off, then says Kaddish. Can you please provide a source that there should be no hefsek between Kaddish and musaf?

Comment: @Danno, No I cannot. But that is why I am here asking the question if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a major question if the Kaddish before Shmoneh Esrei is a preface to Tefillah or is associated with the Ashrei or berachos that precede it.

To satisfy all opinions one should not be mafsik before or after.

See mishna berurah 25:59 that this is apparently a machlokes between magen Avraham who holds to remove tefillin after kaddish and eliyah rabba who holds that is a hefsek

**Discussion and Sources**

Rambam (seder Hatefila pg 329 Frankel edition) writes that Kaddish is said before and after each Tefilah. Rabbenu Manoach (Hilchos Tefila 9:1 s.v. umaschil) writes that since Kaddish is a short tefilah that discusses the geulah Chazal wanted to prevent us from losing hope of the final redemption from the long and arduous galus that we are in. This opinion is echoed by Rabenu Avraham ben haRambam (sefer HaMaspik 200-1) and others.

However, Shibolei Haleket 8 and Rav Av Bais Din and Darkei Moshe (54) write that the Kaddish is associated with what precedes it. (see Rambam Hilchos Tefilah 9:1, Mekoros vetziyunim, Frankel edition)

Most Kaddish is said it is said *after* some other item. For example, Kaddish is said after Torah learning (kaddish deRabanan) or after krias Hatorah or after tefillah or after pesukei dezimra, etc. (Mishna Berurah 55:22)

The clearer problem with hefsek would be between the Torah / Ashrei and Tehillim for returning Torah and the Kaddish that follows it. (That is why in [some shuls](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26097/ha-gommel-before-or-after-kaddish) when someone says Birchas Hagomel as the last aliyah, instead of making the beracha before Kaddish, it is said after Kaddish to eliminate the hefsek.)

Having a break in the davening before Kaddish that precedes Musaf is something to avoid. There is some [discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3383/shabbos-morning-drasha-sermon-before-kaddish-of-musaf) about whether a rabbi's sermon is a hefsek.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/tefillin-removal-on-rosh-chodesh#comment17728_6247 regarding the MA.